# SQL query to exclude weekly data if one zero found

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, replace

Background: In a give scenario at retail store for TSHIRTS, for any style-color combination we have a size scale from xs to xxl.

Would like to achieve:

In any given week, for any size at style-color-store combination having ONHANDUNIT is zero at store then exclude that entire style-color-store (with all other sizes) for that particular week from the resulting data.

Can anyone please help to build that logic?

Code is as below:

```
SELECT

    mat."BASIC_MATERIAL" As SKU,
    mat."DIVISION" As Division,
    mat."DEPARTMENT" As Department,
    RIGHT(mat."STYLE",5) AS Base_Style_ID,
    mat."COLOR" As Color_Code,
    mat."SIZE" As SizeKey,
    r."WEEK" As Fiscal_Week,
    r."STORE" As Store_Location,


    IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN (r."CHANNEL" = 'MARKET' AND r."STORE" NOT IN ('abcd','def','xyz')) THEN r."ONHANDUNIT" ELSE 0 END),0) As Store_OHU


FROM GLOBAL_REPORT As r
JOIN MATERIAL As mat On r."aMAT" = mat."bMAT"

WHERE r."WEEK" BETWEEN '201940' AND '202012'

AND mat."DEPARTMENT" = 'TSHIRTS'

GROUP BY
    mat."BASIC_MATERIAL",
    mat."DIVISION",
    mat."DEPARTMENT",
    mat."STYLE",
    mat."COLOR",
    mat."SIZE",
    r."WEEK",
    r."STORE"
```

**BW data for an example would be as below :**

```
SKU Base_Style_ID   Color_Code  SizeKey Store_Location  Week    Store_OHU
12345BK0001S MKNITS TSHIRT  12345   BK0001  S   1/2020 111  50
12345BK0001M MKNITS TSHIRT  12345   BK0001  M   1/2020 111  10
12345BK0001L MKNITS TSHIRT  12345   BK0001  L   1/2020 111  20
12345BK0001S MKNITS TSHIRT  12345   BK0001  S   2/2020 112  50
12345BK0001M MKNITS TSHIRT  12345   BK0001  M   2/2020 112  0
12345BK0001L MKNITS TSHIRT  12345   BK0001  L   2/2020 112  20
```

**OUTPUT data would be as below excluding 2/2020 week as M size has 0 on hand unit at store.**

```
SKU Base_Style_ID   Color_Code  SizeKey Store_Location  Week    Store_OHU
12345BK0001S MKNITS TSHIRT  12345   BK0001  S   1/2020 111  50
12345BK0001M MKNITS TSHIRT  12345   BK0001  M   1/2020 111  10
12345BK0001L MKNITS TSHIRT  12345   BK0001  L   1/2020 111  20
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected results (as text not image - ideally as DDL/DML).

Comment: @Dale K, I have added a scenario into my query. Hope it helps

Comment: You did see my point about not using images right?

Comment: @Dale K, Sorry about earlier. Made changes again. Let me know if you require anything to help me out in here.